# Check record exists or not into SQLite Database Table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to check **if record exist with ImageName or not into database table**, I am using below code to check that ?

```
// Check for Record using ImageName
    public boolean Exists(String strImageName) {
           SQLiteDatabase db;
           db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from churchTable where ImageName=%s", 
                new String[] { strImageName });
           boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
           cursor.close();
           return exists;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `%s` with `?` so the `strImageName` bind argument is used there:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from churchTable where ImageName=?", 
            new String[] { strImageName });
```

Comment: thanks, will you explain this, why i used ? in place of %s, and what's the difference between these two?

Comment: `%s` is a placeholder for e.g. `String.format()` you're not using. `?` is a placeholder for SQL literal argument binding.

Comment: o.i.c +1 for briefing